# How do you convert Map<String, Person> to Map<String, Integer> in java streams inside collect?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Imagine you have a list of people, Roberts, Pauls, Richards, etc, these are people grouped by name into `Map<String, List<Person>>`. You want to find the oldest Paul, Robert, etc... You can do it like so:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(
                new Person(23, "Paul"),
                new Person(24, "Robert"),
                new Person(32, "Paul"),
                new Person(10, "Robert"),
                new Person(4, "Richard"),
                new Person(60, "Richard"),
                new Person(9, "Robert"),
                new Person(26, "Robert")
        );

        Person dummy = new Person(0, "");
        var mapping = people.stream().collect(groupingBy(Person::getName, reducing(dummy, (p1, p2) -> p1.getAge() < p2.getAge() ? p2 : p1)));
        mapping.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Say, I want to get a mapping in the form of `Map<String, Integer>` instead of `Map<String, Person>`, I can do it like so:

```
var mapping = people.stream().collect(groupingBy(Person::getName, mapping(Person::getAge, reducing(0, (p1, p2) -> p1 < p2 ? p2 : p1))));
```

The steps above are:

- Group by name into `Map<String/*Name*/, List<Person>>`
- Map that `List<Person>` into `List<Integer>`
- Find maximum Integer in those lists.

I was wondering how to do:

- Group by name into `Map<String, List<Person>>`
- Find the oldest person in each group name, getting `Map<String, Person>`
- Convert `Map<String, Person>` into `Map<String, Integer>`. And I want to do all that inside that chain of groupingBy's, reducing's and mapping's.

This is the "pseudocode":

```
var mapping = people.stream().collect(groupingBy(Person::getName, reducing(dummy, (p1, p2) -> p1.getAge() < p2.getAge() ? p2 : p1 /*, have to write some other collector factory method here*/)));
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looks like collectingAndThen is the only way? I just googled that method.

Comment: Do you actually need 3 maps? Or are you asking how to end up with `Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: @shmosel I don't need 3 maps, look at my code to see what type it returns. I don't create 3 maps anywhere.

Comment: Your breakdowns aren't very accurate. None of the examples actually produce any lists. Either way, I don't understand the point of this question. What's the problem with the first way?

Comment: @shmosel how are they not accurate? Please explain.

Comment: I did. There are no lists involved.

Comment: @shmosel what do lists have to do with anything? In any case, maybe you're not understanding it right, what I mean is this. You have name groups you get by doing people.stream().collect(groupingBy(Person::getName)), how do you get oldest people in each group? By nesting another method returning a collector in there and doing people.stream().collect(groupingBy(Person::getName), reducing(dummy, (p1, p2) -> p1.getAge() < p2.getAge() ? p2 : p1)). What is so unclear to you?

Comment: @shmosel So, first you had a list, you nested another collector method and your list is now transformed into a Person object.

Comment: Except there's no list anywhere. `toList()` returns a list; `reducing()` doesn't. And I still don't understand *why* you're looking for this particular formulation.

Comment: @shmosel reread my comment where I nest another collector method. If you don't nest it, you do end up with a list. I simply explained how you can gradually transform one map into another. You're telling me that people.stream().collect(groupingBy(Person::getName) doesn't return Map<String, List<Person>>?

Comment: I got the point. I'm just saying it's not presented very well.

Comment: @shmosel well, to each their own, some people don't have the gift of presenting and some people don't have the gift of understanding.

Comment: You have tagged your question with `[java-8]` but are using Java 10 features.

Comment: @Holger the question is about java-8 features. Streams were introduced in java-8. If you think about it, talking about features that were introduced in one version of java and tagging your question with a higher one, kind of renders tags like java-8, java-9, etc useless. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @POrekhov The fact that this question is about the Stream API is already given by the `[java-stream]` tag. There is no requirement to acknowledge the fact that this API was introduced in Java 8 by tagging every `[java-stream]` question with `[java-8]`. The version specific tags are there to state that you want a version specific answer. Since APIs may change, most notably, they get extended and there might be simpler solutions using the new API version, that’s a restriction. But restricting the API to one version but actively using newer features in the example code is confusing.

Comment: @Holger okay, sorry. I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use `groupingBy` as mentioned in the problem statement, you can still do it like this:

```
final Map<String, Integer> oldestPersonByName = people.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName, Collectors.reducing(0, Person::getAge, Integer::max)));
```

For the reduction you have to pass an identity element, mapping function and a binary operator used to reduce, which is `max` in this case.

Comment: I wonder if -1 can be considered a valid identity if we know age is at least 0.

Comment: That makes sense. Let me change my answer accordingly.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting 0 is better. My issue is that an identity `i` for a function `f` must be a value such that `f(i, x)` returns `x` for any `x`. But I'm not sure if that's any *possible* `x`, or any `x` in the stream. If it's the former, the only valid identity would be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: Yeah, finding the identity element for a reduction is sometimes tricky, and a wrong identity element would lead to subtle bugs which are hard to figure out.

Comment: @shmosel well, if we can be sure that age is always non-negative, `-1` would be a valid identity for `max`. Further, even if negative age values show up due to an error, `max(-1, negative number)` would still be negative, indicating that there is some error.

Comment: I think this is the closest to what I was trying to do, thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is more straightforward to do this with the [3-argument version of `toMap` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-):

```
people.stream().collect(toMap(
        Person::getName, 
        Person::getAge, 
        Integer::max
    ));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be like the following, also using `maxBy` instead of `reducing`.

```
people.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(
        Person::getName,
        collectingAndThen(
            maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge)),
            (Optional<Person> max) -> max.get().getAge()
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thought so, thanks, unfortunately I didn't know about collectingAndThen when I posted this.

Comment: You are redundantly calling `getAge()`. In such a case, it makes more sense to map to the age first, then determine the maximum. `collectingAndThen(mapping(Person::getAge, maxBy(naturalOrder())), Optional::get)` or `mapping(Person::getAge, reducing(-1, Math::max))`, which has the handy abbreviation `reducing(-1, Person::getAge, Math::max)`…